# Can Maven access a repository without exposing my keystore password?

Tags: maven, keystore, client-certificates

The artifact repository I use as my primary mirror just switched over from HTTP to HTTPS.  I had to add a truststore with the CA that issued the server certificate, as well as a keystore containing my client certificate, as per [this guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html).

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252040/can-i-avoid-putting-key-store-password-on-command-line-with-jsse), a commenter mentions giving Maven access to the OSX keyring, but didn't know what to do in Linux.  Has there been any movement on this in the last year+?

As far as I can tell, the "state of the art" is still to put your personal cert in a keystore, then put the keystore password in plain text in your `.bashrc`, which seems just plain wrong.  Are there just not enough client-cert users to care?

Comment: Have you considered that it is far more likely the repository is using a self-signed certificate? If that is the case all you'll need is that cert (or the CA cert used to sign it) in your keystore

Comment: Thanks for the idea Mark, but if I take out the keystore (file name and password) and leave in the settings for the truststore, I get an error.  I've actually been in contact with the guy that maintains this mirror, and he says that a) there was in fact a recent change to require client cert usage, and b) he knows it's a terrible idea but his hands are tied.