# How do you store a username/password in the Mac Keychain using Java?

Tags: java, macos, keychain

I'd like to use the Mac KeyChain to store some username/password combinations for my Java Swing application to use to connect to external services on behalf of the user.

I have found a few sources demonstrating that you can get access to a java.security.KeyStore object by doing:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("KeychainStore", "Apple");
keyStore.load(null, null);
```

However, I can't find any examples of how you use the resulting KeyStore to actually store/retrieve usernames and passwords.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This issue is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727812/storing-username-password-on-mac-using-java. See user erickson's response.

Comment: If I were to go that route, I'd have to be distributing the private key with the app.  That doesn't really seem like the best solution to me.  Isn't there a way to store passwords in the keychain like regular mac apps do?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use java.security.KeyStore to access the Apple Keychain Services.  KeyStore is an abstract wrapper around many providers.  This approach limits the ability to use specific features of an implementation.

Here is a more specific wrapper: https://github.com/conormcd/osx-keychain-java

Also here is the example of using the service see (fig 1-3) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get there "Apple Keychain passwords" from here "Java KeyStore"

The keystore abstraction only wraps the certs in the keychain.

See the difference between the native view of the keychain (bash cmd):

`security dump ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

vs Java's view of the keychain (bash cmd):

`keytool -list  -storetype KeychainStore -keystore ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

Notice that only certificates are included and the listing is shorter.

You will need to use a different wrapper for Keychain that can access all of it's features.

Suggestions:

- github.com/conormcd/osx-keychain-java
- use [swig](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/) to make JNI wrapper

Also read the native docs: [Keychain Services Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9) -- [OS X Keychain Services Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html) (see figure 1-3)

Comment: You can inspect the wrapper to see if I missed a possible path: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/7113349/7u4/4/jdk7u-osx/new/src/macosx/classes/apple/security/KeychainStore.java.html

Answer (score 1):

You could "shell out" to the `security` commandline tool, which lets you store and retrieve passwords from the keychain. It might bring up a popup where you have to allow the access. Also, this does obviously then only work on OSX.

A password could be saved like so:

```
security add-generic-password -s mywonderfulapp -a $username -w $password
```

To retrieve the password you could then do this:

```
security -i find-generic-password -l mywonderfulapp -w
```

To make it easier to capture the output you could use the [JProc](https://github.com/fleipold/jproc) library, e.g. like so:

```
String password = ProcBuilder.run(
    "security", 
    "-i", "find-generic-password", 
    "-l", "mywonderfulapp", "-w"
);
```

Comment: This helps me to store the credentials in the key chain and the library you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Development Guide for Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/04-JavaUIToolkits/JavaUIToolkits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001901-210260) points to the [reference documentation on `java.security.KeyStore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). I'm not familiar with `KeyStore`, but perhaps you'll find what you need there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has not been at all helpful. It seems to be all about storing keys & certs, but I really need to store username/password combos.

Comment: I think this is for the Java Keystore, not the macOS Keychain. I don't think it applies.